# MySQL Referencing same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, date

I have two small tables which I have outlined with sample data below. They contain two different types of sales stats for reps grouped by a certain timeframe. I am having trouble configuring the join so that the sales rep, time period, and  two sets of numbers all line up. Ideally I want to see the Rep, Date Grouping, and both sets of sales numbers all on the same row. Currently it seems that one row of data will get blown out for all records for one rep.

```
Table 1 - Closed
Sales Rep Name | Date Group | # Won

Table 2 - Won
Sales Rep Name | Date Group| # Lost
```

Desired Outcome

```
Sales Rep Name | Date Group | # Lost | # Won    
Joe Schmo      | June-16    | 25     | 15    
Joe Schmo      | July-16    | 38     | 12    
Joe Schmo      | Aug-16     | 38     | 12
```

Right now I am joining as below and doesn't appear to work

```
 Select Sales Rep Name, Date Group, Lost, Won
    From Table 1 - Closed c
    Left Join Table 2 - Won w
    ON c.Sales Rep Name=w.Sales Rep Name
    Left Join Table 2 - Won w
    ON c.Date Group =w.Date Group
```

Comment: any reason you don't have won and lost in the same table?

Comment: The sales figures that I am counting in my SUM fields when I created these table are derived from a single table, and both can be present on a single row (customer record). A single customer can have both a win and a loss, so a customer needs to be counted for both the win and the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this should work for you

```
SELECT
closed.date_group,
closed.`sales_rep_name`,
closed.lost,
won.won
FROM
lost
INNER JOIN won ON closed.`sales_rep_name` = closed.`sales_rep_name`
WHERE lost.date_group = won.date_group
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked like a charm. Always simpler than I make it out to be. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, could you set my answer as accepted?